# Using Process.extract in fuzzywuzzy and the all max similar choices

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, similarity, fuzzywuzzy

I have the following input-

```
query = 'Total replenishment lead time (in workdays)'
choices = ['PLANNING_TIME_FENCE_CODE', 'BUILD_IN_WIP_FLAG','Lead_time_planning', 'Total replenishment lead time 1', 'Total replenishment lead time  2']
print(process.extract(query, choices))
```

I get the following output-

```
[('Total replenishment lead time 1', 92), ('Total replenishment lead time  2', 92), ('Lead_time_planning', 50), ('PLANNING_TIME_FENCE_CODE', 36), ('BUILD_IN_WIP_FLAG', 26)]
```

But I just want all the best choices with a maximum similarity ratio even if the ratio is similar for two choices.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function included in the fuzzywuzzy library which is called extractBests. I would suggest as following:

```
best_score = process.extractOne(query, choices)[1] #gets the score of the best match
matches = process.extractBests(query, choices, score_cutoff=best_score) #returns list with equally goot matches (tuples with match and ratio)
```

Comment: alternatively you could also process the output of the process.extract() function wit list comprehension:

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you would like to receive the following output:

```py
[('Total replenishment lead time 1', 92), ('Total replenishment lead time  2', 92)]
```

You can achieve this by filtering the results of `process.extract`

```py
matches = process.extract(query, choices, limit=None)
max_ratio = matches[0][1]
best_matches = []
for match in matches:
  if match[1] != max_ratio:
    break
  best_matches.append(match)
```